# If $F$ is a field and $\phi:F[x] \to F[x]$ is a ring automorphism,with the property that $\forall \lambda \in F:\phi (\lambda)=\lambda$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $F$ is a field and $\phi:F[x] \to F[x]$ is a ring automorphism,with the property that $\forall \lambda \in F:\phi (\lambda)=\lambda$,then prove that exist $a,b \in F:\phi(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $\phi(x)=ax=b$ is incoherent for $(a,b) \neq (0,0)$.

Comment: @masaheb Should that be $\phi(x) = \color{red}{ax + b}$ instead?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132130/automorphisms-of-kx-1-x-2-dots-x-n-that-fix-k) for the general case.

Comment: A solution is also given in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3019922/homomorphisms-and-automorphisms-on-polynomial-rings) for $K=\Bbb R$, which generalizes to an arbitrary field $K$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $\phi(x) = p(x)$. $\phi$ is completely defined by $p$ and the condition $\phi(\lambda) = \lambda$ for all $\lambda \in F$.

Prove that if the degree of $p$ is greater than one, then $\phi$ can't be onto. And that if the degree of $p$ is equal to zero, then $\phi$ isn't one-to-one.

Therefore $\phi(x) = ax+b$ which leads to a ring automorphism.